# Android Calculator gives wrong answer

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm making a android one-line calculator. So far this calculator works when I write it in javascript, c++ and c#, but I can't get it to work in android (java). Here is my code:

```
            String seq = String.valueOf(sec.getText());
            ArrayList<Integer> allNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int i = 0; 
            ArrayList<String> allSigns = new ArrayList<String>();
            String currentNums = "";
            for (i = 0; i< seq.length(); i++)
            {
                if (seq.charAt(i) != '+' && seq.charAt(i) != '-' && seq.charAt(i) != '*' && seq.charAt(i) != '/')
                {
                    currentNums+=seq.charAt(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    allNums.add(Integer.parseInt(currentNums));
                    currentNums="";
                    allSigns.add(String.valueOf(seq.charAt(i)));
                }
            }
            allNums.add(Integer.parseInt(currentNums));

            int result = (Integer)allNums.get(0);
            for (i = 1; i <= allNums.size(); i++)
            {
                if (allSigns.get(i-1) == "+")
                    result+=allNums.get(i);
                else if (allSigns.get(i-1) == "-")
                    result-=allNums.get(i);
                else if (allSigns.get(i-1) == "*")
                    result*=allNums.get(i);
                else if (allSigns.get(i-1) == "/")
                    result/=allNums.get(i);
                else
                {
                    sec.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I'm calling the function by onClick event. The app doesn't crash, but only gives me as answer the first number. For example: 34+31-4*8/1    It returns 34. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `==` operator to compare string values, which is not correct.  For objects (including Strings), `==` compares the references to determine if they refer to the same object.

To compare string values, use [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead:

```
if ("+".equals(allSigns.get(i-1)))
```

Comment: Well I didn't know that. I tried it, but now the app just crashes. Any ideas? Is this also for char, or just for String?

Comment: `allNums.get(i)` must be throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since you're looping from `1` to `allNums.size()`. Try changing the calls to `allNums.get(i-1)` as you're doing in `allSigns`.

Comment: If you meant to make from allNums.get(i) to allNums.get(i-1) its not working. They are different, because the sign is always smaller with one than the number of numbers. Hope that you understood me.

Comment: I fixed it! It should be < .size(), but it was <= .size(). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

String comparison in java uses `"oneString".equals("another")`  not `==`

```
            ...
            if (allSigns.get(i-1).equals("+"))
                result+=allNums.get(i);
            else if (allSigns.get(i-1).equals("-"))
                result-=allNums.get(i);
            else if (allSigns.get(i-1).equals("*"))
                result*=allNums.get(i);
            else if (allSigns.get(i-1).equals("/"))
                result/=allNums.get(i);
            else
            ....
```

Should do it.

Comment: Well I didn't know that. I tried it, but now the app just crashes. Any ideas?